# How to give space between x-axis values in android using MpandroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Hi How to give space between below x-axis values in android using MpandroidChart Libray

[Hello for the below image refrence In x-axis I am displaying value want to give equal space between strings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou2h5.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method setSpaceBetweenLabels()

```html
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(int characters)
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: give me the complete method

Comment: This is the complete method. XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(int characters)